# Entire Document or Selected Fields only Performance in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb, mongoose

I have been thinking on how I can make my app in NodeJS to go faster, so I have tried querying for only some fields and the entire document, because at MongoDB Documentation says its faster to query for certain fields. The problem is it's seems to me incorrect, where am I failing? Here is the code I am using I have made it to save to csv to get a Chart from Libreoffice:
http://pastebin.com/G8KRRY3n

- First Option (A) is get the entire Document.
- Second Option (B) is get some fields.

Here is the graph I toke from it (Every operation in miliseconds):
http://prntscr.com/5oofoz

I process almost 9500 users. As you can see, at first (0~200) items procesed, It's the same, but then the second options start to grow in time... I have tried to switch the order of the options because of the garbage collector has something to do, but the results are almost the same.

Yes, the first option is faster at first elements, So the question is... In a High Traffic webapp which option is the recomended? Why? I am newbie at performance field so I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: You would be better served by showing how you are coding your tests. But yes it is possible that the overhead involved in removing the fields to just specific fields in a projection can cause a slowdown. But your test conditions are too broad without specifics. Depends on what is in memory, index selections, actual data required to be returned an queried, etc, etc. You could provide your test details but it's all very subjective.

Comment: @NeilLunn I get two String, and one Number as fields. I use Windows 8.1u2 Spanish 64 Bits 8Gb Ram and I7 (Laptop). While the process is working I don't touch anything. And yeah it's what I think, but I though they got the fields and not that they deleted it from the gotten document, now It can make sense... Any Recomendation to learn to make tests for performance and make it faster? Thanks

Comment: What I was really saying that without some code, and idea of what the documents really look like and documentation of how you are running your tests it's all to hard to say. Depending on the conditions there is no definitive statement that can be made that say "projection is good" or "projection is bad" for your case. Generally speaking, unless you are doing so to see 3 fields only from a document containing 64 fields of complex data then there is little to no specific advantage. Tests are always good because they tell you the truth.

Comment: @NeilLunn I can't show Specific code, but yes, The Schema has 213 lines, but some of them corresponds to arrays of objects. So the thing is, if the Schema is small the Option recomended by MongoDB is the best at first, and the other (Get the entire document) would be better for big schemas, but at the end the tests would be the only truth to choose the best option. Isn't it? Thanks!